# Mod QOS Request Level Control

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I have a small confusion with mod_qos. With Mod_qos I am trying to Request Level Control. But I tried my level best to achieve my goal but I was failed to do that.
I have a simple objective to achieve.

1. I don't want to limit connection/threads per IP address. I want to limit the connection for every URL from the server.

I have tried this:

**QS_LocRequestLimitMatch "^.*/en.+" 4**

URL example:

1. http://xx.x.xx.x/en/2svcqivtliz1-56757-2/ex2.iso
2. http://xx.x.xx.x/en/355353534-sssjs-2/ex3.iso

My (QS_LocRequestLimitMatch "^.*/en.+" 4) works for only single URL. As I try with another second URL it gives me 503 Error. I am testing with the Internet download manager.